# Why are my pages linking to 404 pages using WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I made some pages in Wordpress and displayed a navigation so the user can click to go to those pages.

When you click on any of the links, other than the Home link, it will go to a 404 Page not Found Page and display a message as the one below:

> The requested URL /new_mtt/about-us-2
>   was not found on this server.

I realized I don't have a page.php file. Do I need that in order to view pages other than the index?

Why are my pages not working correctly?

Comment: Did WordPress create the `.htaccess` file in the directory where your `index.php` file is? The `mod_rewrite` rules are necessary for the permalink structure that your 404 error suggests WP is using.

Comment: I don't have an .htaccess file in the folder with my index.php file. Where can I get the .htaccess file I need to put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has to be a .htaccess-file in your Wordpress-directory. In there should be the rules for url rewriting.
The problem could be: that file is missing, the file is corrupt or mod_rewrite is not allowed.

Comment: Yes, I have an .htaccess file in my general wordpress folder but not in the folder where my index.php file is. Where does it need to be?

Comment: Check on your Wordpress-Adminpage for something like `If your .htaccess file were writable, we could do this automatically...` on Settings > Permalinks panel.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely need to regenerate your permalinks -- that solves the problem around 90% of the time. Click on Settings, Permalink; then pick any option that's not selected, hit Save, pick the option you originally wanted again (likely a custom structure with %postname%), hit save again, and verify that it saved.

If it can't save, as with the previous answer, make sure you check that your .htaccess file has global write access.